# asp.net - Measuring Page loading when javascript enabled/disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do it exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use firefox and install FireBug add-on

it has a tab that showsthe loading times against each object/resource into the page

Comment: Enable tracing for the page you want to debug and check out the information in trace.axd.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx